# Terraform fix no matching subnet found for vpc with id vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following terraform code and when I try to `terraform apply --auto-approve` it gives me this error

> Terraform fix no matching subnet found for vpc with id vpc

I think this is because the `data` block is trying to get the Subnet ID's right after the subnets are being created. Because, after 1 minute or so, I can again do a `terraform apply --auto-approve` and it works fine.

How can I fix this problem?

```
# -------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------
# Create VPC
module "ecs_vpc" {
  source = "./modules/7_vpc"
}

# -------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------
# Create SUBNETS
module "ecs_subnets_public_1" {
  source = "./modules/8_subnet"
  SUBNET_CIDR = "10.0.128.0/18"
  VPC_ID = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id
  SUBNET_TAGS = {"Name" : "terraform-subnet-public-1"}
}

module "ecs_subnets_private_1" {
  source = "./modules/8_subnet"
  SUBNET_CIDR = "10.0.192.0/18"
  VPC_ID = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id  
  SUBNET_TAGS = {"Name" : "terraform-subnet-private-1"}
}

# -------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------
# Create IGW
module "ecs_igw" {
  source = "./modules/9_igw"
  IGW_TAGS = {"Name" : "terraform-igw"}
  VPC_ID = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id
}

# -------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------
# Create EIP for NAT
module "nat_eip" {
  source = "./modules/10_eip"
  EIP_NETWORK_BRODER_GROUP_REGION = "us-east-2"
  EIP_TAGS = {"Name" : "terraform-nat-eip"}
}

# -------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------
# Create NAT
data "aws_subnet_ids" "public_1" {
  vpc_id = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "*terraform-subnet-public-1" // or two filter by a unique word use; *private*
  }
}

output "public" {
  value = data.aws_subnet_ids.public_1.id
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_1" {
  vpc_id = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "*terraform-subnet-private-1" // or two filter by a unique word use; *private*
  }
}

output "private" {
  value = data.aws_subnet_ids.private_1.id
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating subnets in modules `ecs_subnets_public_1` and `ecs_subnets_private_1`, you shoudn't use `data source` to get the information about these subnets. The `./modules/8_subnet` module should return all the information that it wants to expose to the parent module through `outputs` as indicated in [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html) of the TF docs. This is done using [outout](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/index.html#module-structure):

> Output values to return results to the calling module, which it can then use to populate arguments elsewhere.

So your `./modules/8_subnet` would have `output` for the subnet id. Something like this:

```
output "subnet_id" {
   value = aws_subnet.mysubnet.id
}
```

Then to access it in parent module you would use the following instead of the data source:

```
module.ecs_subnets_private_1.subnet_id

# and

module.ecs_subnets_public_1.subnet_id
```

Nevertheless, the likely reason why your `data.aws_subnet_ids` fail is because they probably run before the subnets are actually created. To fix that you would have to add `depends_on`:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "public_1" {
  vpc_id = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "*terraform-subnet-public-1" // or two filter by a unique word use; *private*
  }

  depends_on = [module.ecs_subnets_public_1]
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_1" {
  vpc_id = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "*terraform-subnet-private-1" // or two filter by a unique word use; *private*
  }

  depends_on = [module.ecs_subnets_private_1]
}
```